# HTML/Browser/CSS - Webpage Seems Larger On Server

Tags: html, css, browser

> **Similar Question:**
>
> [Why does my website appear smaller on a live server than when deployed locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025139/why-does-my-website-appear-smaller-on-a-live-server-than-when-deployed-locally)

So I wanted to reask this question, but please don't say there is already a duplicate. I thought the answer of that page is just basic information, and didn't fix my problem.

My question is similar, the **same page** in my **PC renders fine**(Firefox, Chrome), but the same one on a **server rendered smaller** by Firefox(Chrome OK). My local webpage is using the URI`file:///` and I have hosted a page on a free server, of course the URI would then be`html://`. That is all I know.

Local: [image]!

Web: [image]!

As you can see, both **screen sizes are exactly the same**, the **CSS is the same**, **not zoomed in**, I suspect it is how Firefox handle px sizes differently, but this is the 1st time happening. Why? How to fix?

### Extra Information:

**I discovered if I zoom in in Firefox 1 time in the page on the server, it is the same size as the page locally**

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible you're zoomed in? Try pressing control + 0 to reset the zoom, or using control + the mousewheel.

Comment: I have same experience. (Almost).
My problem reverse from the OP. When i check my chrome browser, local web was zoom 90% while live was 100%. I must fix all the css to looks like 90%... lol 
Thx GriffinG.